# How to add a jQuery Listener for 2 events?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an event in a table that if clicked a function fires, but I also want the same function to fire if an item on a dropdown select option is selected.

My working code for the table TD if clicked is:

```
$('td[id^="tblcell"]').click(function() {
...
... do something
...
});
```

how can I add code to the first line so that the same function ALSO executues if the SELECT is changed?

Something like:

```
$('td[id^="tblcell"]').click(function() OR ('select[id^="selectlist"]').onChange(function() {
```

But that obviously doesn't work due to the syntax error... what is the correct way to code this? (if it is even possible).

I am using PHP and the latest jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put your code into a function and call it in two seperate handlers.

```
$('td[id^="tblcell"]').click(doStuff);
$('select[id^="selectlist"]').on('change', doStuff);

function doStuff(event) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = function () {
    // do something
}

$('td[id^="tblcell"]').click(f);
$('select[id^="selectlist"]').change(f);
```